# How to play audio faster but keep pitch?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, dvd-audio

Is there an application for Ubuntu that can play audio faster but maintain its pitch?

This is possible in Windows using an application like PowerDVD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [Playitslowly](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playitslowly) [image: Install playitslowly]

There is [PlayitSlowly](http://29a.ch/playitslowly/), intended to do this (among others things). You can also save a sound file with altered speed or pitch.

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Thank you,this answers my question. At the same time I found another solution, that works pretty well. VLC is capable of doing what I asked for when activating the "scale audio tempo in sync with playback rate" filter which can be found under advanced options. CU

Comment: @YSN, by all means, add this as an answer!

Comment: @Firefeather: good idea!

Answer (score 10):

VLC is capable of keeping the pitch as well when activating the "scale audio tempo in sync with playback rate" filter which can be found under advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

For hackers: Many years ago I wrote a software that can do that which is now on GitHub ([pyTranscribe](https://github.com/bluenote10/pyTranscribe)). However, the author of [PlayitSlowly](https://29a.ch/playitslowly/) has done a very good job and I would recommend PlayitSlowly over pyTranscribe because it comes with many features that I didn't had time to include like:

- More standard UI
- Better controls over pitch/tempo
- Easier to open files (not just from the command line)
- File history
- Automatic loop support
- Supports exporting the pitch shifted / tempo adjusted file

Glad to see someone has solved this :).

You only might want to try pyTransribe if you are into alternative / keyboard-based UIs (pyGame based):

[image: pyTransribe]